# Create JSON column in Spark Scala

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some data that needs to be written as a JSON string after some transformations in a spark (+scala) job.
I'm using the to_json function along with struct and/or array function in order to build the final json that is requested.

I have one piece of the json that looks like:

```
"field":[
    "foo",
    {
        "inner_field":"bar"
    }
]
```

I'm not an expert in JSON, so I don't know if this structure is usual or not, all I know is that this is a valid JSON format.
I'm having trouble to create a dataframe column with this format and I want to know what is the best way to create this type of data columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dataframe with a bunch of columns you want to turn into a json string column, you can make use of the `to_json` and the `struct` functions. Something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "string1", Seq("string2", "string3")),
  (2, "string4", Seq("string5", "string6"))
  ).toDF("colA", "colB", "colC")

df.show                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
+----+-------+------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|colA|   colB|              colC|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
+----+-------+------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|   1|string1|[string2, string3]|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
|   2|string4|[string5, string6]|                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
+----+-------+------------------+

val newDf = df.withColumn("jsonString", to_json(struct($"colA", $"colB", $"colC")))

newDf.show(false)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
+----+-------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                      
|colA|colB   |colC              |jsonString                                              |                                                                                                                                                                                      
+----+-------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+                                                                                                                                                                                      
|1   |string1|[string2, string3]|{"colA":1,"colB":"string1","colC":["string2","string3"]}|                                                                                                                                                                                      
|2   |string4|[string5, string6]|{"colA":2,"colB":"string4","colC":["string5","string6"]}|                                                                                                                                                                                      
+----+-------+------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

`struct` makes a single StructType column from multiple columns and `to_json` turns them into a json string.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi.

We are using that approach now, but we still have issues when trying to get the output that I put in the question. Can you try to give an example where you take some columns and get that specific result?